# Two rows of windows in tmux

Tags: tmux

I tend to have several windows open in tmux at once.  I also automatically name them according to which task I'm working on.  As such, I am running out of room for the labels of my tmux windows.  Is there any way to configure the tmux bar to be 2 rows tall and fill both rows with the window names?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?  I note (8 year after the original question) current tmux versions now do have the option to have multiple status lines.  However by default tmux only uses one line for window names.  I'd be interested if people have the required formatting command to get tmux to use the extra lines.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't. However, here are two alternatives:

1. Use multiple sessions. Each task could have its own session, or you might find a logical way to divide your tasks among a smaller number of sessions. The `choose-session` (by default, <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>) command can be used to switch quickly among them.
2. The `choose-window` (<kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>) command provides a convenient interface to list and select windows from a vertical menu.

Comment: Remember the default mode key is `Ctrl-B`, unless it has been changed recently.  I use `Ctrl-\\` myself.